# SQL, tables connected via foreign key - how to make ID-Numbers identical?

Tags: sql-server

i want to connect different tables via foreign key -binary and unary relations.

for example:

```
  create table[tab2]
(ID INT Not null PRIMARY KEY)


create table[tab1]
(ID INT Not null PRIMARY KEY,
 Tab2ID INT Not null constraint tab1_tab2 foreign key referenes tab2(ID)--binary relation )

create table[tab3]
(ID INT Not null PRIMARY KEY,
tab2ID int Not null unique constraint tab2_tab3 references tab2(ID)) --unary relation
```

i want to give the ID-PrimaryKeys an automatic value. I've tried it with IDENTITY but it didn't worked, when i wanted to enter data in the tables via visual studio. the IDs didn't get automatic values, what wasn't alowed cause "NOT NULL".
and the values of the via relation conencted columns of to connected tables, have to have the same value right? 
how do i do that?

thanks in advance.
sorry for poor english-knowledge

is function "NEWID()" an option for my purpose? are the values of connected tables automatically matching?

Comment: **WHAT** exactly didn't work with the `IDENTITY` ?? This **is** the best and most suitable way to have auto-generated primary keys - you should really try to make this work.

Comment: tab2 must be created before tab1 if tab1 references tab2.

Comment: the insert-command is in conflict with a foreign-key-constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the identity column on Tab2, and make sure you insert into Tab2 first.  You will not be able to insert into Tab1 or Tab3 before inserting into Tab2, bc the FK constraint will fail (since the value you are trying to insert doesn't exist into Tab2).

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

First, create Tab2 with the ID column as an identity specification (you will either need to drop Tab2 and recreate with the specification, or drop the column and add a new one):

```
create table [tab2]
(
    ID INT Not null PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
)
```

Then insert a row into Tab2:

```
DECLARE @Tab2Id INT;
INSERT Tab2 DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT @Tab2Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Now you can insert into Tab1 and Tab3 using the new ID from Tab2

```
INSERT INTO Tab1(Id, Tab2Id) VALUES(1, @Tab2Id); 
INSERT INTO Tab3(Id, Tab2Id) VALUES(1, @Tab2Id);
```

(Alternatively you can also specify IDENTITY columns for Tab1 and Tab3 `Id` columns, but note that you will still always need to insert into Tab2 first, before inserting the Tab2 id into the other tables).

Comment: what is scope_identity for? and the paragraph witn "declare..." is not supposed to be in "create table.." right? cause i got an error if i named the column "ID" and not specific "IDtabX"

Comment: @noclue123 scope_identity returns the last identity value inserted.  It is a simple way to figure out what the automatically generated integer value was.  The DECLARE clause is simply declaring a variable named 'Tab2Id' which you assign the automatically generated ID to so you can reuse it in your other insert statements.  Your names aren't important so calling the columns IDtabX shouldn't make a difference (just change the statements appropriately).

Comment: So the "ID" from tab2 is not similar to "Tab2id" in declare-paragraph?

Comment: @noclue123 no, it has nothing to do with it.  It could just as well be `DECLARE @MyVariable INT;`.  You can completely ignore the first and 3rd line if you want, it just makes subsequent inserts slightly easier for you (otherwise you'll have to select from tab2 to figure out what the auto-generated id was, and update it in your insert statements).

Comment: i get an error that the value NULL cannot be insert in an different attribute in my tab2-table. the error gets highlitgehted  by "INSERT Tab2 DEFAULT VALUES"

Comment: @noclue123 then you need to supply values for Tab2.  I used the DEFAULT VALUES syntax because your example code indicates that Tab2 only had the one PK column.  You will need to supply values for at least all non-nullable columns in the format `INSERT INTO Tab2(ColA, ColB, ...) VALUES('col a value', 'col b value', ..)`.

Comment: oh yeah sorry. i get the error that it's not possible to insert an specific value in the identity-column of the tab1-table, if identity_insert is turned off. so i googled and it seems that you can turn the identity_insert on just for one table, is that right? what do i do than? sorry if that are too many (dumb) questions but i'm pretty new to sql

Comment: @noclue123 if you have an identity specification for a given column then you must exclude the column in your inserts (do not specify a value for the identity column).  So just don't include IdTab1 in your insert statement.  You probably have an INSERT somewhere that looks like INSERT Tab1 (IdTab1, ColA, ColB), change it to INSERT Tab1(ColA, ColB).  (ColA and ColB are just examples).  IdTab1 will be automatically generated for you.

Comment: ah okay. thank you so much i think it actually works finally